# Java query for postgresql's interval method not working

Tags: java, postgresql

I'm writing postgresql query. When I run the query

`"reservatio0_.DATE_ >(NOW() - '60 MINUTES'::INTERVAL)`" on pgAdmin it works fine, but in java I get

> QuerySyntaxException, unexpected token: : bla bla

if I run this code

```
List<Reservation> list = em.createQuery( 
                                    "select r " +
                                    "from Reservation r " +
                                    "where r.group.id=:groupName " +
                                 "  and  r.date >(NOW() - '60 MINUTES'::INTERVAL) " +
                                    "order by r.date asc")
                                    .setParameter("groupName", groupName)
                                    .setParameter("number", number)
                                    .setMaxResults(1)
                                    .getResultList();
```

Comment: Try `interval '60' minutes` instead

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want this be done from PG and not on the Java side (create a Calendar and set the time accordingly)?

Comment: unrelated: you shouldn't name your columns "date" as it is a reserved keyword. https://drupal.org/node/141051

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I just think that this would be more elegant

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i got querySyntaxException, unexpected token: '60 minutes'

Comment: So apparently the database obfuscation layer known as "JPA" does not support ANSI SQL there (`interval '60' minutes` is an ANSI compliant interval literal). You will need to check the JPA documentation on how to use intervals and dates in JPQL (or HQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, i think yours is the right answer. ill search further

Answer (score 2):

try to replace your colon operator (`:`) with `\\:`
that would escape this special character..

Comment: unexpected token "\" it says

Answer (score 0):

IIrc you have to put the interval in front of the amount, like this:

```
and  r.date >(NOW() - interval '60 minutes')
```

Comment: "unexpected token ' " it says